# Wordpress Logged In Code Is Different Than Logged Out Code?

Tags: wordpress

My question is that, when I'm logged into Wordpress, the code is "normal" and working. However if I'm logged out (or in incognito mode), the code is "altered" and the site is not working as it's supposed to.

Here is a screenshot of the logged in code:

[image: Logged In Code]

And here is the logged out code:
[image: And here is the logged out code]
Just in case you guys are wondering, the URL is http://2ndsky.org/sensucomm/project/jack-daniels-multicultural-campaign/.

Did anyone else encounter problems like this before?

Comment: Do you have conditional code that displays different things to logged-in users?

Comment: I don't think I have such codes :(

Comment: Well the, issue is obviously malformed html in your template. Can you post the php for your page template?

Comment: Hmm it's here: http://2ndsky.org/sensucomm/wp-content/themes/themetrust-weston/page.txt

Could it also have something to do with my plugins? I used Background Videos for SiteOrigin Page Builder to put the video background up.